# SQL Query Returning `NaN` in Node Environment

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb

In my Node backend I am running a simple SQL query that, up until recently was working correctly. Now however, part of the result I get is returning `NaN` rather than the value I'm expecting. Again, not sure why. And this was working up until recently. If I take the query and values and plug them directly into SQL Workbench I get the correct result.

The function in question is called from another file/function like so:

```
async getBranches(ctx, guid) {
  return await this.db.Srt.getDivisions();
}
```

This is the `getDivisions` function:

```
  async getDivisions() {
    const query = `
      SELECT id_number AS division, description AS branch FROM cbr.divisions
        WHERE description NOT IN ("Administrative");
    `;
    const values = [];
    const result = await this.db.query(query, values);

    if (result.length > 0) {
      console.log('result: ', result); // See result below
      return result;
    }
    return [];
  }
```

This is what logs to the console for `result`:

```
result:  [
  { division: 1, branch: NaN },
  { division: 2, branch: NaN },
  { division: 3, branch: NaN },
  { division: 5, branch: NaN },
  { division: 6, branch: NaN },
  { division: 7, branch: NaN },
  { division: 8, branch: NaN }
]
```

In SQL Workbench I get the following (correct) result for the same query:

```
division| branch
      1 | Chicago
      2 | New York
      3 | Los Angeles
      5 | Atlanta
      6 | Denver
      7 | Seattle
      8 | Sacramento
```

What is the issue here? Again, this was working - but now is not, as described above.

UPDATE:
Okay, very strange, after reverting to our previous version of `mariaDB` which was `"mariadb": "2.1.0"`, the function works again, and returns the values as expected. I have no idea why this works for that version, but not for `"mariadb": "2.1.3"`. Can anyone offer clarity on this?

Comment: Are you calling `getDivisions` from another async function?

Comment: Yes. I  have added that above. Is there a reason you ask? Can that pose a problem?